# Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-rc5

I am working on angular 2 application that is 2.0.0-rc.4 version. While running to project I am getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined in the index.html file Could somebody tell me what the problem could be

Snapshot of the errors
[image]

Snapshot of the exact point where the error is occuring

[image]

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Analytics Platform</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/ipad.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/styles/platform.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/styles/vendor/vex.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/styles/vendor/vex-theme-default.min.css">
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    </script>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <!--build:js /app/dist/lib.js-->
    <script src="/libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="/app/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <!--/build-->
    <!--build:js /app/dist/app.js-->
    <script>
        System.import('app/bootstrap').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <!--/build-->

    <base href="/" />
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <analytics-app>
        <style>
            div.main {
                width: 350px;
                background: white;
                position: relative;
                top: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .main table tr td {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .main table {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .main span {
                padding-left: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="main">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="/app/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif" /></td>
                    <td><span>This Analytics model is loading. Please stand by.</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </analytics-app>
</body>
</html>
```

The application path

[image]

Comment: Angular has been final for two years now, and is at version 7. Why do you still use a release candidate version, with ancient tooling?

Comment: We have plans to migrate in the future but for now need to support the legacy application